# Как сделать заливку кнопки при нажатии в tkinter

Tags: python, изображения, button, tkinter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 - Клавиша зажата button-1

2 - Клавиша не зажата и без фокуса

---

Мне нужно, чтобы кнопка (рисунок-2) при зажатии (Button-1) на ней не меняла свой рельеф на рисунок-1

---

Исходник, фотография снизу

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
canvas = Canvas(root, bg="white")
canvas.place(x=-5,y=-5)


ico_disstbl = PhotoImage(file="close_distbl.png")

but = Button(canvas, bg="red", image=ico_disstbl, relief=FLAT, overrelief=GROOVE)
but.place(x=100-18+5, y=100-27+5, width=27, height=18)

root.mainloop()
```

[Фото](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsEWb.png): [image: введите сюда описание изображения], скачайте и назовите `close_distbl.png`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте параметр `activebackground` для того чтобы обрабатывать цвет фона кнопки при ее нажатии

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
canvas = Canvas(root, bg="white")
canvas.place(x=-5, y=-5)


ico_disstbl = PhotoImage(file="close_distbl.png")

but = Button(canvas, bg="red", image=ico_disstbl, activebackground="red", relief=SUNKEN)
but.place(x=87, y=78, width=27, height=18)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А как рельеф кнопки не изменять при этом?

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно, чтобы при клике рельеф не менялся, можно просто вместо `Button` использовать `Label`. Для удобства можно отнаследоваться от `Label` и заставить новый класс притворяться кнопкой.

```
import tkinter as tk


class FlatButton(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, overrelief=tk.FLAT, command=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.relief = kwargs.get('relief', tk.FLAT)
        self.overrelief = overrelief

        if command:
            self.bind('<1>', command)

        self.bind('<Enter>', self.mouse_in)
        self.bind('<Leave>', self.mouse_out)

    def mouse_in(self, event):
        self.config(relief=self.overrelief)

    def mouse_out(self, event):
        self.config(relief=self.relief)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white")
canvas.place(x=-5, y=-5)

ico_disstbl = tk.PhotoImage(file="close_distbl.png")

but = FlatButton(canvas, bg="red", image=ico_disstbl, relief=tk.FLAT, overrelief=tk.GROOVE,
                 command=lambda event: print('Hello!'))

but.place(x=87, y=78, width=27, height=18)

root.mainloop()
```